# Cognos Analytics 11 is removing all spaces on saved prompts values

Tags: cognos-bi, cognos-11

When I create a report view, cognos is trimming the spaces of the value of each prompt. Then, when I try to run the report view, Cognos can't bind the saved values with the prompt values.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying your database legitimately and deliberately stores values with leading or trailing spaces?  ...and the Cognos report view is not saving what you actually entered as prompt values?

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion change the filter by having the field trimmed as well as the parameter

For example, Detail filter would be:
`trim([Customer Name]) = trim(?PromptName?)`